# ckEditor - Change the insert image button to just put image tags into the editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

im trying to convert ckeditor into a simpler interface and am incorporating bb code into my side so thought i might as well remove the whole insert image interface.

Instead, i would like the insert image button to simple put '[img][/img]' into the ckeditor body.

If possible also get the cursor between the two, but thats another issue.

Any help?

Comment: If you're going to show [img] instead of the real image, why do you bother with CKEditor at all instead of using any classic BBCode editor?

Comment: i am allowing users too c+p their current forum code.

When echoing out the data after its saved, i run a function that replaces the [img] tags with html tags.

However vice versa is causing issues on saving etc so looking at another way round this.